# Use of continue in python - how to break out of an individual loop?

Tags: python

I have written some code that contains several while loops.

```
    answer = "yes"
    while answer == "yes":
        name = input("what is your name?")
        while len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha():
            print("okay")
            break
      else:
          print("error")
          continue
      job = input("what is your job?")
      while job.isalpha():
          print("great")
      else:
          print("not so great")
          continue 
      age = input("how old are you?")
      while age.isnumeric():
          print('nice')
      else:
          print("not so nice")
          continue
```

What I want the code to do is check for a valid name entry, and if it is invalid re-ask the user for their name. I want it to do the same thing with their job. Unfortunately, when I use continue after the job statement, instead of just re-asking for their job, it re-asks for their name as well. Does anyone know how to make it only re-ask for the job, and not re-do the whole program? Does anyone know how I could replicate this for multiple while loops I.e. Asking for job, name, age, star sign etc.?

Thank you.

Comment: the value you are checking with the `while` statement has to be updated inside the `while`. otherwise just use `while True` with `break`

Comment: You should replace your while loops with if statements

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `while True` because answer never change.
2. It's useless while for 1 expression and 1 break.

You should put everything on a while True and check:

```
 while True:
     name = input("what is your name?")
     job = input("what is your job?")
     if len(name) > 0 and name.isalpha() and job.isalpha():
         print("great")
         break
     print("error")
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the question into a seperate fuction to de-duplicate the code. It will ask again and again as long as the answer is not satisfactory.

```
def ask(s):
    r = ""
    while not r or not r.isalpha():
        r = input(s)
    return r

name = ask("What is your name?")
print("Okay. Your name is {}.".format(name))
job = ask("What is your job?")
print("Great. Your job is {}.".format(job))
```

Comment: Thank you - would this work for asking for multiple inputs, including ones that are numeric only?

Comment: Well, the `ask` function is designed to ask for alphabetic inputs, and rejects anything else. You can of course change that behaviour however you want.